# Библиотеки функций GLSL

Tags: opengl

У меня появилась идея компоновки одной программы из нескольких шейдеров. Один шейдер будет содержать точку входа, а остальные будут реализовывать некоторые функции и использоваться как библиотеки. Это, например, позволит обойтись без всяких Uber shader'ов, часто используемых в DX, а основной шейдер будет маленьким и простым. Эти библиотечные шейдерные объекты могут быть независимы от типа, то есть один и тот же код можно скомпилировать, как `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`, `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER`, `GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER` и так далее. Но если в программе есть фрагментный шейдер с точкой входа main, и универсальный библиотечный шейдер, созданный как не фрагментный, то программа не скомпонуется.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ создать универсальный тип шейдеров, который компоновался бы с главным шейдером любого типа? Или придётся дублировать все библиотечные шейдеры по 5 раз для разных типов?

Comment: Оказалось, что скорость компиляции - мелочь по-сравнению с компоновкой. У меня библиотека на 11 КБ GLSL кода компилируется за 35 мс, а линковка с ней к времени компоновки прибавляет 100 мс, хотя на самом деле используется только одна функция из десятка, определённых в этой библиотеке.
 Только почему-то первая компиляция для каждого типа шейдеров, даже если они занимают три строчки, занимает 400 мс. Это что такой "прогрев" компилятора шейдеров в драйвере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, нет. Спецификация не позволит (не знаю как насчет версий выше 1.20). Единственный вариант, который можно использовать - это передавать код несколькими строками. Первая строка - библиотечные функции, вторая - основной код шейдера. Такое предложение было в книге Роста "OpenGL Трехмерная графика и язык программирования шейдеров". Страница 154, цитирую:

> Передача исходного кода шейдера не в одной, а в нескольких строках имеет
> следующие преимущества:
>
> 1. Можно систематизировать некоторые общие части исходного кода
> 2. Можно использовать совместно для нескольких шейдеров какой-либо "заголовочный" код (подобно заголовочным файлам в C++)
> 3. Можно совместно использовать значения #define для контроля процесса компиляции.
> 4. Можно включать в код функции, определенные разработчиком или взятые из других библиотек.

Появилась ещё одна идея. Она описана в комментарии, но я решил её вынести в сам ответ.

> Есть ещё один вариант. При запуске программы скомпилировать 3 шейдерных объекта (по одному каждого вида). У каждого объекта код будет один и тот же, и содержит он ваши библиотечные функции. Далее, перед линковкой большого шейдера, вы можете приаттачить к нему эти уже скомпилированные шейдерные объекты, содержащие библиотечный код, к программному объекту. Далее просто линкуете. Таким образом вы можете избежать долгой компиляции и линковки всей шейдерной программы.
>
> PS Только не забудьте потом объявить прототипы нужных вам функций в объекте, содержащим точку входа.

Comment: >К сожалению, нет. Спецификация не позволит (не знаю как насчет версий выше 1.20).

 Так я и предполагал. Интересно, почему они это не сделали? Вроде несложно должно быть.

Comment: >Первая строка - библиотечные функции, вторая - основной код шейдера.

 Про несколько строк я знаю. К тому же их можно вручную конкатенировать. Но каждый раз будет компилироваться большой шейдер, а компиляция может быть медленной. Да и памяти шейдеры будут больше занимать. Я тогда наверное сделаю ленивую загрузку ресурсов в моём движке, и компилировать буду шейдер только тогда, когда он будет нужен. Поэтому когда он будет использоваться с шейдерами одного типа, он будет скомпилирован один раз.

Comment: Есть ещё один вариант. При запуске программы скомпилировать 3 шейдерных объекта (по одному каждого вида). У каждого объекта код будет один и тот же, и содержит он ваши библиотечные функции. Далее, перед линковкой большого шейдера, вы можете приаттачить к нему эти уже скомпилированные шейдерные объекты, содержащие библиотечный код, к программному объекту. Далее просто линкуете. Таким образом вы можете избежать долгой компиляции и линковки всей шейдерной программы.
PS Только не забудьте потом объявить прототипы нужных вам функций в объекте, содержащим точку входа.

Comment: Так я об этом и говорю. Только компилировать я их буду не при запуске программы, а при первом использовании(т. е. лениво). Если все программы, использующие шейдер-библиотеку, будут только фрагментными, то и компилировать библиотеку придётся только один раз. Это будет делать мой движок автоматически. У меня ещё эта идея до того, как я задал этот вопрос появилась, но я решил узнать, возможно ли обойтись без этого.

Comment: Кстати, есть предположение, что дело вовсе не в спецификации.

У каждого типа шейдера свои наборы инструкций, предназначенные для своего типа процессора. Вы пытаетесь создать один унивирсальный шейдер, для всех типов процессоров, с одним набором инструкций. Современные производители графических адаптеров пытаются создать процессоры (и уже даже создали), способные выполнять все 4 вида шейдеров (тесселяционые, тоже сюда входят). Это так называемая унифицированная шейдерная архитектура (на википедии есть подробная инфа). Только она еще не стала массовой, чтобы стать стандартом.